# Why int primitive type not deprectaed in Java

Tags: java, integer, int

In java if `Integer` can be used instead of `int` and `Integer` providing extra features then my question is why is `int` not being deprecated, and why `int` primitive type so extensively used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple reason why it is not deprecated is that **int** is faster. And although you can use both but `Integer` is a better option(some may disagree as *Integer introduces an extra overhead of boxing and unboxing*), as it can handle **null**. `int` null will become 0.

From the docs:

> However, very different things are going on under the covers here. An
>   int is a number; an > Integer is a pointer that can reference an
>   object that contains a number.
>
> ...
>
> An int is not an object and cannot passed to any method that requires
>   objects. A common case is in using the provided collection classes (
>   List , Map , Set ) - though it is possible to write versions of these
>   classes that provide similar capabilities to the object versions. The
>   wrapper classes ( Integer , Double , etc) are frequently required
>   whenever introspection is used (such as in the reflection API).

**EDIT:-** The Joshua Bloch's reason is also good:

```
// Hideously slow program! Can you spot the object creation? public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long sum = 0L;
    for (long i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
         sum += i;
    }
    System.out.println(sum); }
```

> This program gets the right answer, but it is much slower than it should be, due to a one-character
>   typographical error. The variable sum is declared as a Long instead of
>   a long, which means that the program constructs about 2^31 unnecessary
>   Long instances (roughly one for each time the long i is added to the
>   Long sum). Changing the declaration of sum from Long to long reduces
>   the runtime from 43 seconds to 6.8 seconds on my machine.

Also check this [int versus Integer](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/intvsinteger.html)

Comment: `An int is not an object and cannot passed to any method that requires objects.` I agree with this be the opposite is possible so why not make `int deprecated`?

Comment: You may like to think the case where user submitted a form, and doesn't supply any value for int. You will end up getting 0 by default. It makes sense, when that field is not null in the database, but who knows you might refactor your table, down the road, to make that nullable.

Comment: @pronox:- Also to summarize the point Objects provide facilities for polymorphism, are passed by reference, and are allocated from the heap. Conversely, primitives are immutable types that are passed by value and are often allocated from the stack.

Answer (score 3):

Boxed types have poorer performance and require more memory, Primitives are faster. And to avoid creating unnecessary objects.

`Integer` is an immutable type, once you created, you can't change it, taking much memory and high overhear compare to `int`

Answer (score 1):

> An int is a number; an Integer is a pointer that can reference an
>   object that contains a number.

- int is a primitive type. If not set, the default value assigned is 0. Integer is an object which may contain an int. If the Integer object is not set, the default value is null
- If you can use int do so. If the value can be `null` or is used as an Object e.g. `Generics`, use Integer

Answer (score 0):

An int is a set construct. For example, only one "int 10" exists and is immutable. Integers on the other hand are full classes that contain an int field among others, have many more methods and are mutible.

int for speed and Integer for versatility.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an method with int as argument, you do not have to nullcheck because it is a primitve type.